# Filtering empty json response in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Question - I am trying to filter the image property of this json response.
Some of the arrays dont contain images and therefore I want to filter them out.
New to angular and typescript.

```
this.music.searchArtists(this.searchQuery).subscribe(
  data =>{
    this.results = data.artists.items;
    console.log(this.results);
    
  }
)
```

Response
[image: data.artists.items]

2 contains images, 3 does not (therfore want to exclude it)
[image: second image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
this.results = data.artists.items.filter(item => item.images.length > 0);
```